# Redirect URL with specific section in it - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, url, redirect, model-view-controller

I have an existing page with several questions (like faq) with a URL like

Main help URL: sitename.com/help
URL of a specific section: sitename.com/help#topic123

Now the requirements are changed and I have been told to redirect (temporary) the /help to the homepage with a query string as sitename.com?showhelp.

I have used a redirect rule in web.config which is working fine for the main help page.

```
Requested URL: sitename.com/help
Redirected to URL: sitename.com?showhelp
```

**PROBLEM**
When I am redirecting a specific topic URL to a new one, it still shows the #topic123 at the end of URL like

```
Requested URL: sitename.com/help#topic123
Redirected to URL: sitename.com?showhelp#topic123
Required URL: sitename.com?showhelp
```

Rule used:

```
<rule name="newhelp" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^help" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="?showhelp" redirectType="Temporary" />
</rule>
```

I have also tried to redirect from the controller action method, but this does not solve the problem. I am unable to read the #topic123 part from Request.Url

Comment: That's a [URI fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) which is only used by the browser. It appears there because some Javascript code put it there. It's never passed to the *server*.

Comment: So if I request in browser sitename.com/help#topic123, shouldn't it go to the server?

Comment: Read the link. It says that fragments aren't sent to the server by any browser. The links *shouldn't* contain fragments, unless this is an SPA that's meant to handle fragments on the browser before calling the server. Eg an Angular or React application that uses its own controllers to handle the requests and call the backend service

Answer (score 1):

Use (#.+) to get the extra fragments

```
<rule name="newhelp" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^help(#.+)?" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="?showhelp{R:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />
</rule>
```